# Everything I tried to update I received this message

Tags: package-management, dpkg, mysql, chromium, deb

```
$ sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra gstreamer1.0-vaapi libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7
  libhtml-template-perl libllvm11 libva-wayland2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mysql-cluster-community-server-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-cluster-community-server-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 37 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/24.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 155 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 276726 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-cluster-community-server-core_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-cluster-community-server-core (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-cluster-community-server-core_8.0.28-1
ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/ibd2sdi', which is also in package mysql-community-server-core 8.0.2
8-1ubuntu20.04
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-cluster-community-server-core_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Do you have a question?  Your question text appears to be nothing but a paste, without any descriptive text that has a question (*details in the title should also appear in the question as not everyone uses a desktop machine which can read the title when reading your question text; and please use {code} tags around pastes*)

Comment: To fix, run: `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-cluster-community-server-core_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb`